# Slow running Macro and Avoiding Select when pasting between Excel sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet which looks at performance figures for a rolling 5 week period. I created a macro which copies the data from week 4 to week 5 and repeats for each work sheet before leaving week 1 empty so I can paste in the most recent data.

The macro is slow and seems to get slower every week. To try to make it faster I put in code to clear the existing contents before pasting in the new data. This worked at first, but it has slowed again.

This is the code for the first two sheets to be copied. It does the same for the rest of the sheets but the code is the same.

```vb
Sub Move_data() ' Copies all data across to advance sheet by one week.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
    Sheets("Week 5").Select ' Clears current entry from week 5
    Range("A1:S161").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    
    Sheets("Week 4").Select 'Selects data to copy from week 4
    Range("A1:S161").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Week 5").Select 'Pastes data to week 5
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    Sheets("Week 4").Select 'Clears data from week 4
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    
    Sheets("Week 3").Select 'Selects data to copy from week 3
    Range("A1:S161").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Week 4").Select 'Pastes data to week 4
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Having looked at various articles I think that part of the problem lies in using ".Select" so frequently.

I tried to replace these two lines:

```vb
Range("A1:S161").Select
Selection.Copy
```

with

```vb
Range("AR:S161").Copy
```

It didn't seem to have much impact on the time it takes for the macro to run.

How could this code work more efficiently?

Comment: `Sheets("Week 4").Range("A1:S161").Copy Sheets("Week 5").Range("A1")` is how you would copy paste without selecting or activating the sheet.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Could you just rename your worksheets? Instead of moving `Week 4` data to `Week 5`, you could just rename `Week 4` to `Week 5`. You would have to make sure you avoid duplicate names but you could do that with a temp naming convention or something.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I'll give that a try. I'd already read through that article.. I just don't understand most of it.

Comment: @urdearboy Thanks for the idea, that was what I tried originally, however, the data is pulled through to another sheet where each teams performance is separated out to show the 5 week position. When the sheet names are changed, the formulas on the team over view page no longer work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only interested in moving the values from one sheet to another then `Value Transfer` is ideal solution since it's more efficient than copy/paste. However, if you also need to copy formulas from one sheet to the next then you will need to switch to Copy/Paste.

```
Sub Mover()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim i As Long

For i = 5 To 1 Step -1
    wb.Sheets("Week " & i).Range("A1:S161").ClearContents
    If i <> 1 Then
        wb.Sheets("Week " & i - 1).Range("A1:S161").Copy
        wb.Sheets("Week " & i).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the help, I couldn't get it to work at first, but realised that I had to be on the week 5 worksheet when running the macro. As the macro is assigned to a command button on the home page, i've just added a line of code before the "For" to select sheet 5 prior to the rest of the code running. Again, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Sub Move_data() ' Copies all data across to advance sheet by one week.
    Const RNG As String = "A1:S161"
    Dim n As Long

    For n = 5 to 2 step - 1
        Sheets("Weeek " & n).Range(RNG).Value = Sheets("Weeek " & (n-1)).Range(RNG).Value
    Next n

End Sub
```

Assigning values directly is often faster.